# Utilizar valor de una variable en comando batch

Tags: batch

Lo que querría hacer es poder insertar una variable en un comando como **RENAME**. El objetivo es cambiar el nombre del archivo a la hora y fecha actual. Este es el código que he intentado utilizar (para que entiendan mi intención):

```
SET nombre=%time%, %date%

rename archivo1.txt %nombre%.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`14:38:00, 03/08/2017.txt`:

- necesita ir entre comillas o el espacio en blanco confundira la sintaxis del rename.
- es un nombre de archivo ilegal en windows (`:`, `/`).

Puedes reemplazar los caracteres ilegales usando [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441422/replace-character-of-string-in-batch-script), lo que nos daría:

```
set nombre=%time%, %date%
set nombre=%nombre:/=_%
set nombre=%nombre::=-%
rename archivo1.txt %nombre%.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un problema en tu código, y es que la variable `%nombre%` va a dar como resultado un nombre de archivo no válido. Aqui tienes una opcion que da como salida un archivo tipo `log-2017.08.03-14.40.txt`:

```
set FICHERO_DATE=%DATE:~6,4%.%DATE:~3,2%.%DATE:~0,2%
set FICHERO_TIME=%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%
set FICHERO=log-%FICHERO_DATE%-%FICHERO_TIME%.txt
rename archivo1.txt %FICHERO%
```